# EF (Core): Modified entity with added relations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Assuming that I have an entity which has a one to many navigations to another entity. For example:

```
public class Person {

    public int Id {get; set;}
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers {get; set;}
    ...
}
public class PhoneNumber {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public String number {get; set;}
   public int PersonId {get; set;}
   public Person PersonNavigation {get; set;}
}
```

In case I want to update the person name and at the same time add a few number to that person's phone number or delete some numbers, for example:

```
Person person = db.Set<Person>().SingleOrDefault(x=> x.Id == 1);
person.Name = "James";
deleteOneNumber = person.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.number == "555");
person.PhoneNumbers.Remove(deleteOneNumber);
foreach(var number in new String[] {"123","456"}){
   person.PhoneNumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber{ Number = i});
}
```

How exactly should I define the framework to apply all changes? In accordance with EF Core documentation, the `Update` method will change the state of all entities to `Modified` while `Add` would change those to `Added`. In case I use the `Modify` method here, with respect to the fact that the newly added numbers do not exist in the database, they cannot be modified.

Edit:

**Assume this is a disconnected scenario.**

Comment: Your scenario falls into [Disconnected Entities - Mix of new and existing entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#mix-of-new-and-existing-entities) *with auto-generated keys*, so `Update` should do the job.

Comment: @Arrrr, You didn't tell whether you are facing any problem with your current query. If you face any error with the current query then what is the error message?

Comment: @TanvirArjel: The exception is `An error occurred while updating the entries.`

Comment: @IvanStoev: It doesn't do so, I've tested the behavior of EF and it blindly set all states to modified!

Comment: @Arrrr It probably depends on the EF Core version you are using, because the `Update` method behavior has changed between versions. The documentation is for the latest version and I believe it works as explained.

Comment: Actually it's mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities) right after the `InsertOrUpdate` example: *"This behavior was introduced in EF Core 2.0. For earlier releases it is always necessary to explicitly choose either Add or Update."*

Comment: @IvanStoev: You are right, I actually noticed that. However, based on my long experience with EF core, there are some minor issues. I think if an upgrade doesn't solve this then I have to move this post to github.

Answer (score 1):

Utterly old but stumbled upon this while posting my own issue so I'll make an attempt.

First of all, I'm not sure if the relation from PhoneNumber to Person works, if it does ignore this part, if it doesn't then check how to use custom foreign keys and not the standard ones (PersonNavigationId/PersonNavigation).

```
public class PhoneNumber {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public String number {get; set;}

   public int PersonId {get; set;}
   [ForeignKey(nameof(PersonId))]
   public Person PersonNavigation {get; set;}
}
```

If you are not using lazy loading your code won't work because your entities are not being tracked (I also don't see any update/save calls), EF can't detect your changes with similar code that you have above. For EF to detect those changes and easily update related entities you need to let it know it should track the relations, you do this by including (eager loading) the related entities. I'm assuming that DB if your example is a DbContext.

```
Person person = db.Set<Person>().Include(p => p.PhoneNumbers).SingleOrDefault(x=> x.Id == 1);

person.Name = "James";

deleteOneNumber = person.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.number == "555");
person.PhoneNumbers.Remove(deleteOneNumber);

foreach(var number in new String[] {"123","456"}){
   person.PhoneNumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber{ number = i});
}

db.Set<Person>().Update(person);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I, however, would prefer something like this, most of it is syntax but async/await frees up threads while waiting for IO to complete. It assumes you've followed a standard naming convention for DbContext.

```
var person = await db.Persons.Include(p => p.PhoneNumbers).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == 1);

person.Name = "James";

deleteOneNumber = person.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault(pn => pn.number == "555");
person.PhoneNumbers.Remove(deleteOneNumber);

foreach(var number in new String[] {"123","456"}){
   person.PhoneNumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber{ number = i});
}

db.Persons.Update(person);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for **similar problem** using TrackGraph

### Synopsis

I want to **Modify only few columns** of the entity as well as **Add\Modify nested child entities**

- Here, I am updating `Scenario` entity and modifying only `ScenarioDate`.
- In its child entity, i.e. navigation property `TempScenario`, I am adding a new record
- In the nested child entity, `Scenariostation`, I am adding as well modifying the records

```
public partial class Scenario
{
    public Scenario()
    {
        InverseTempscenario = new HashSet<Scenario>();
        Scenariostation = new HashSet<Scenariostation>();
    }
    public int Scenarioid { get; set; }
    public string Scenarioname { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Scenariodate { get; set; }
    public int Streetlayerid { get; set; }
    public string Scenarionotes { get; set; }
    public int? Modifiedbyuserid { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modifieddate { get; set; }
    public int? Tempscenarioid { get; set; }

    
    public virtual Scenario Tempscenario { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Scenario> InverseTempscenario { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Scenariostation> Scenariostation { get; set; }
}


public partial class Scenariostation
{
    public Scenariostation()
    {
        Scenariounit = new HashSet<Scenariounit>();
    }

    public int Scenariostationid { get; set; }
    public int Scenarioid { get; set; }
    public int Stationid { get; set; }
    public bool? Isapplicable { get; set; }
    public int? Createdbyuserid { get; set; }
    public int? Modifiedbyuserid { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modifieddate { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Scenario Scenario { get; set; }
    public virtual Station Station { get; set; }
}

public partial class Station
{
    public Station()
    {
        Scenariostation = new HashSet<Scenariostation>();
    }

    public int Stationid { get; set; }
    public string Stationname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public NpgsqlPoint? Stationlocation { get; set; }
    public int? Modifiedbyuserid { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modifieddate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Scenariostation> Scenariostation { get; set; }
}
```

- With EF Core, data update in a disconnected scenario is tricky if you don't want to make 2 database round trips.
- Even though 2 database trips seems not significant, it can hamper performance if the data table has millions of records.
- Also, if there are only few columns to be updated, including columns of nested child entities, `Usual Approach` will not work

#### Usual approach

```
public virtual void Update(T entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

    var returnEntity = _dbSet.Attach(entity);
    _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

But the problem here for a disconnected EF Core update, if you use this  `DbContext.Entry(entity).EntityState = EntityState.IsModified`, all the columns will updated.
and so some columns will be updated to its default value i.e. null or default data type value.

Further more, some records of `ScenarioStation` won't be updated at all because the entity state will be `UnChanged`.

So inorder to **update only the columns** which are sent from the client, somehow **EF Core needs to be told**.

### Using ChangeTracker.TrackGraph

Recently I found this `DbConetxt.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph` method which can be used to mark `Added`, `UnChanged` state for the entities.

> **difference**  is that with `TrackGraph`, you can add custom logic, as it iteratively navigates through Navigation properties of the entity.

#### My custom logic using TrackGraph

```
public virtual void UpdateThroughGraph(T entity, Dictionary<string, List<string>> columnsToBeUpdated)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

    _context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(entity, e =>
    {
        string navigationPropertyName = e.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name;

        if (e.Entry.IsKeySet)
        {
            e.Entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            e.Entry.Property("Modifieddate").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;

            if (columnsToBeUpdated.ContainsKey(navigationPropertyName))
            {
                foreach (var property in e.Entry.Properties)
                {
                    if (columnsToBeUpdated[e.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name].Contains(property.Metadata.Name))
                    {
                        property.IsModified = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.Entry.State = EntityState.Added;
        }

    });

}
```

With this approach, I am able to easily handle only required column updates as well as new additions/modifications for any of the nested child entities and its columns.